# Can tkinter buttons be used to change canvas objects repeatedly?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a GUI to represent the graphical interpretation of the triangle symmetry group (i.e. the reflections and rotations of a equilateral triangle that leaves it unchanged).
Ideally I would have liked to do this in an animated fashion, but that is beyond me, so I am just changing the labels on the points, and would like to do so using a button for reflection or for rotation, but I can't get the buttons to actually change the value of the coordinates that I need them to.

I am trying to swap the coordinates of p1, p2 and p3 in the below code
`

```
def rf(p1, p2, p3):
    p4=p3
    p3=p2
    p2=p4
def ro(p1, p2, p3):
    p4=p1
    p1=p2
    p2=p3
    p3=p4
    print(p4)
def buttons(p1, p2, p3):
    l=tk.Button(top, text="Rotate", command=ro(p1, p2, p3))
    k=tk.Button(top, text="Reflect", command=rf(p1, p2, p3))
    triangle(p1, p2, p3)
    text(p1, p2)
    k.pack()
    l.pack()
buttons(p1, p2, p3)
top.mainloop()
```

`

when I run it, and press the rotate button, p1 prints with the original value, and only prints once no matter how many times the button is pressed.
How can I fix this, and is there a better package to be able to actually animate this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments to commands in a button like that.
What you have done it actually evaluates ro(p1, p2, p3) as the button is being created, takes the return of that method (which is None) and saves that as the command.  So when you press the button, it is calling None....which does nothing of course.

Normally, when you make a button, the command should just be a METHODS NAME ONLY
Example:
l = tk.Button(top, text="Rotate", command=ro)

This is a python thing, where you can treat whole methods like they are variables.
So maybe do that, and change the method to be something like this:

```
def ro():
    p4=p1
    p1=p2
    p2=p3
    p3=p4
    print(p4)
```

If you really do need to pass arguments, this is the most common workaround:

```
l = tk.Button(top, text="Rotate", command=lambda: ro(p1, p2, p3)
```

There is kinda a long explanation on why that works, you can lookup up what the lambda keyword does in python to understand it more.

**Edit, as mentioned in the comments**:

Using your variables in the way you are may cause some strange things to happen.  Namely that it will not "save" changes to the variables.  This is happening because the variables you are working with have a scope limited to the function they are used in.  That is to say, the names you are using are created in the function so they are removed once the function completes.  There are a few ways to fix this.

One way to do this, is to have the names saved globally, drop the arguments and tell the function that they are global:

```
p1 = 5  # these are just examples, make sure they are established
p2 = 7  # on the root level, or at least on the level that your
p3 = 12 # button is made or lower

def ro():
    global p1, p2, p3 # this will insist on using the globally named variables and not things specific to this function
    p1, p2, p3 = p2, p3, p1 # oh, btw, you can do this to save space and not have to make a p4
```

You will have to drop the lambda in this case and just have it call 'ro' as the command.
This will do what you want, but has a couple issues:

1. you cannot use the ro() method for anything other than rotating those three things
2. using the 'global' keyword is generally frowned upon and I personally never use it

What you may be happy with, is something more like this:

```
p = [14, 12, 83]
q = [1, 43, 18, 75]

def ro(x):
    first = x.pop(0)
    x.append(first)

print(p)
ro(p)
print(p)
print()
print(q)
ro(q)
print(q)
```

If you run that, you will see it rotates all the numbers in an arbitrary list.
This way, you can store your triangles in a list and then make your button like this:

```
l=tk.Button(top, text="Rotate", command=lambda: ro(p))
```

and it will change the list given to the ro() command and you will not need to worry about what scope the variable is because you pass it with the 'p' in `ro(p)` and it makes changes to whatever is passed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that does work with the lambda, however, it doesn't seem to permanantly change the value of p1, which is needed to move to the next value of the rotation, nay suggestions on that?

Comment: Yeah, python has some confusing levels of scope for variables, and I am betting that is what is going on here.   I'll edit my answer so I can explain it in length a bit more than what a comment like this can do.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been a while since I have worked in python, mostly use C so I am rather unfamiliar with the global variable conventions!--marking as correct now!